# OpenLayers move and rescale image ol.interaction.Draw

Tags: javascript, openlayers

In my app I wrote an ol.interaction.Draw code that allow me to draw a circle everytime I click on one map panel, and this circle work good for me because I can move, rotate and rescale proportionally it. This is my code:

```js
 map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Modify({
                features: this.features,
                deleteCondition: function (event) {
                    return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(event) && ol.events.condition.singleClick(event);
                }
            }));
            this.draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                features: this.features,
                type: 'Circle',
                draggable:true;
                   });
            this.draw.on('drawstart', function () {
                this.features.clear();
            }, this);
            this.map.addInteraction(this.draw);
```

But I would like to draw an image (e.g. with the source media/image/landscape.png), instead of one circle, but with the same features (drag and drop, rotate, rescale proportionally). How I could do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably want to draw circles but style them using your png as an icon.  Scaling would be based on the circle radius.  Circle geometry doesn't include rotation but by using a geometryFunction in the interaction you could set a rotation and use that to rotate the icon (the angle needs to be adjusted depending on which edge or corner of the icon is used for the rotation).

```js
var white = [255, 255, 255, 1];
var blue = [0, 153, 255, 1];
var width = 3;
styles = [
  new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: [255, 255, 255, 0.5]
    })
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: white,
      width: width + 2
    })
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: blue,
      width: width
    })
  }),
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: width * 2,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: blue
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: white,
        width: width / 2
      })
    }),
    zIndex: Infinity
  })
];

var treeStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
       src: 'https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/oak-tree-icon-png-17.png'
    })
});

styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
    if (feature.getGeometry().getCenter) {
        treeStyle.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(feature.getGeometry().getCenter()));
        treeStyle.getImage().setRotation(feature.getGeometry().get('rotation'));
        treeStyle.getImage().setScale(feature.getGeometry().getRadius()/(150*resolution));
        return treeStyle;
    } else {
       return styles;
    } 
}

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source,
    style: styleFunction
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, vector],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [-11000000, 4600000],
        zoom: 4
    })
});

var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: 'Circle',
    geometryFunction: function(coordinates, geometry) {
        var center = coordinates[0];
        var last = coordinates[1];
        var dx = center[0] - last[0];
        var dy = center[1] - last[1];
        var radius = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        var rotation = Math.PI - Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        geometry = geometry || new ol.geom.Circle(center, radius);
        geometry.setCenter(center);
        geometry.setRadius(radius);
        geometry.set('rotation', rotation);
        return new ol.geom.Circle(center, radius);
    },
    style: styleFunction
});
map.addInteraction(draw);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very very very much @Mike !! The icon appear and i can rotate and resize it! The only thing that I don't understand it is why, instead of the icon, it still draw the circle when I click?

Comment: It's similar to this example https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/draw-shapes.html  When you draw circles there is a center, radius and rotation which can be used to produce other shapes, or in our case style the circle center as an icon.  It if displays as a circle check you have the style function set correctly (only circle geometry has a getCenter method).

Comment: I edited the styleFunction in this way:  `styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
         if (feature.getGeometry().getCenter) {
              treeStyle.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(feature.getGeometry().getCenter()));
              treeStyle.getImage().setRotation(feature.getGeometry().get('rotation'));
              treeStyle.getImage().setScale(feature.getGeometry().getRadius()/(150*resolution));
              return treeStyle;
          } else {
             return treeStyle;
          }
      }`  and now it print the icon, but also the circle

Comment: and the icon is not draggable and scalable..the circle instead yes..maybe I have to change something else or edit something in ol.interaction.Draw?

Comment: That will return treeStyle when it's not a circle.  I think you must have some other style set somewhere in your code which is styling the circle as a circle.  I don't see circles when I run the snippet.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, I had another style set in my code that I didn't see